# How to Executing Shell commands through android app?

Tags: android

Firstly I'm new to Android.

How to execute the following shell command

```
echo "1" > /sys/devices/enable
```

in an android app.

I referred many link's but I didn't get the solution.

Is there any permission that I should mention in the manifest file to execute the shell commands in the app???.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write in Java?

```
try{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("/sys/devices/enable"));
    fw.write('1');
    fw.close();
}catch(IOExceprion e){}
```

If you really want to invoke a shell, try this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"1\" > /sys/devices/enable");
```

Make sure your device is rooted first before trying any of the above mentioned approaches.

Comment: Hi @alex, I´m trying to use the command "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4", how should I write it using your code?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
     try{
            Process process;            
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo "1" > /sys/devices/enable");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shiv, I´m trying to use the command "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4", how should I write it using your code?? Thanks!!