# How to write a ffmpeg command shell in C

Tags: android, c, video, ffmpeg, native

it´s possible I´m asking a nonsense but I´m a bit noob... I´m trying to write native code in Android to change the resolution of a video using a FFmpeg. I compiled the library of FFmpeg and I added it to my project correctly after used the NDK. But now I want to execute this FFmpeg command shell:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4
```

I need to execute it in a C file using the JNI but I don´t know how to call the equivalent methods of the command...

I think I´m having a similar problem than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619918/how-to-use-ffmpeg-on-android)

Thanks for help!!

Comment: use system() function to execute commands

Comment: like that: "system(ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4);"?? I´ve just tried it and it doesn´t seem it´s doing anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
system("ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4");
```

or

```
char str[]="ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4";
system(str);
```

**INFO**

```
int system (const char* command);
```

Execute system command.

**EXAMPLE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char command[50];

   strcpy( command, "ls -l" );
   system(command);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 480x320 output.mp4` is this gives expected output when you run from the terminal?

Comment: well, I´m really using another path. I´m doing it on Android, so I can´t try the command from the terminal...

Comment: Which path are you using ? How did know that this command is working As expected.see this http://shreyagarwal.blog.com/2011/04/20/executing-shell-commands-in-android-applications/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741221/how-to-executing-shell-commands-through-android-app

Comment: Okey!! I´m trying it but I don´t know how to write it:
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-i", I DON´T KNOW HOW TO WIRTE IT HERE});

Comment: I did search for you. please ask about the above issue here only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741221/how-to-executing-shell-commands-through-android-app

Comment: Hi, did it work for you ? Can a command line be used in code ?

Comment: @ransh Yes we can execute commands using **system** function.