# Android Program to run Shell Script

Tags: android

I am New to Android Programming, i need to creat an Android application to Run Shell Script on button Click Event.
i am using below command but no action is happening.

```
 Process p;
                 try {
                     p = new ProcessBuilder()
                     .command("/data/test.sh")
                     .start();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } finally {
                     if(p!=null) p.destroy();
                 }
```

1. I have created "data" folder and kept my shell script there.
2. Having phone root permission.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

To execute a shell script you first need to give it execution permission by using `chmod +x`.
Then, you can use `p.waitFor()` (after `start()`) and wait for it to finish execution.

To read the output of  your script, you can do the following:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
// reading part comes here
```

If you are running this in an emulator, you need to look at this:
http://russelldavis.blogspot.in/2011/01/rooting-android-emulator.html

Sources:
[execute shell command from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android)
[How to Executing Shell commands through android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741221/how-to-executing-shell-commands-through-android-app)

Aside:
[Difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)

Comment: Thank, Will try to follow ... :)